# How to create a parameterized infix macro in sweet.js

Tags: javascript, macros, infix-notation, sweet.js

In the [bluebird wiki article about JavaScript optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments), the author mentions that passing the `arguments` keyword to any function (except `apply`) will cause the parent function to not be optimizable.  I would like to create a [sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/) macro that allows me to write standard idiomatic JavaScript but will take care of the optimization killer.

Ideally, I would like a macro that would take the following function:

```
function foo() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return args;
}
```

And output something like this:

```
function foo() {
    var args = [];
    for(var i, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return args;
}
```

I am having trouble with getting the sweet.js macro syntax correct, however.  [This is what I have so far](http://sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html#let%20arguments%20=%20macro%20%7B%0A%09rule%20infix%20%7B%0A%09%09%20%5B%5D.slice.call%20%7C%20%0A%09%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09%5B%5D;%0A%09%09for(var%20i%20=%200,%20len%20=%20arguments.length;%20i%20%3C%20len;%20i++)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09args.push(arguments%5Bi%5D)%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20toArray()%20%7B%0A%09var%20args%20=%20%5B%5D.slice.call%20%20arguments%0A%09return%20args;%0A%7D):

#### example.sjs

```
let arguments = macro {
    rule infix {
         [].slice.call | 
    } => {
        [];
        for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
            args.push(arguments[i])
        }
    }
}

function toArray() {
    var args = [].slice.call  arguments
    return args;
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
function toArray() {
    var args$2 = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return args$2;
}
```

I tried making my macro have parenthesis around the `arguments` keyword and also include the `var` declaration, but without any success.  I tried something like this:

#### invalid macro

```
let arguments = macro {
    rule infix {
        var $var = [].slice.call ( | ) 
    } => {
        var $var = [];
        for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
            args.push(arguments[i])
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
SyntaxError: [syntaxCase] Infix macros require a `|` separator
414: 
                                ^
```

Comment: actually, your first function is fine since you return an array, not an arguments. you also don't need the loop, or the temporary variable.

Comment: @dandavis For my purposes, I want the loop. Did you get a chance to read the linked article? It explains why one would not want to pass `arguments` to `Array.prototype.slice.call`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so there are a couple of ways to do this. Putting arguments
inside of parens doesn't work because infix macros can't match outside
of enclosing delimiters so when the `arguments` macro gets invoked it
sees zero tokens before or after it (the error should be clearer).

Your other solution is running into hygiene problems since the
`arguments` macro needs access to the `args` identifier but infix
macros are not allowed to match before the equals sign when it's in a
`var` statement so it can't actually match the `args` identifier.

So couple of solutions. The easiest is to just do something like what
the bluebird wiki suggested:

```
macro argify {
    rule { ( $arg ) } => {
    var $arg;
    for (var i, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    }
}

function foo() {
    argify(args)
    return args;
}
```

You could also go the unhygienic route (not really recommended but
`arguments` is already kinda unhygienic so…):

```
let function = macro {
    case {$mname $name ( $parens ...) { $body ... } } => {
    letstx $args = [makeIdent("args", #{$mname})];
    return #{
        function $name ( $parens ...) {
        var $args = [];
        for (var i, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
            $args.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        $body ...
        }
    }
    }
}

function foo() {
    return args;
}
```

**Edit:**

I just thought of another solution that would allow you to keep your current syntax by overriding `var`:

```
let var = macro {
    rule { $args = [].slice.call(arguments) } => {
        var $args = [];
        for(var i, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
            $args.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    rule { $rest ... } => { var $rest ... }
}

function foo() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a bummer about not being able to match outside of enclosing delimiters.  It would have been nice to not change any of our code base (or developer's habits) and just have sweetjs as part of the build step.

Comment: Just edited in another potential solution that should let you not change any of your code.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought about going that route.  I was in the middle of putting in a feature request on your issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite the same result, since it has a function wrapper (though it's invoked with `apply`), but it doesn't require you to override `var` and can be used in any expression position.

```
macro copy_args {
  rule {} => {
    function() {
      var len = arguments.length;
      var args = Array(len);
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        args[i] = arguments[i];
      }
      return args;
    }.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

let slice = macro {
  rule infix { []. | .call(arguments) } => { copy_args } 
  rule infix { []. | .apply(arguments) } => { copy_args } 
  rule infix { Array.prototype. | .call(arguments) } => { copy_args }
  rule infix { Array.prototype. | .apply(arguments) } => { copy_args }
  rule { } => { slice }
}

function go() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return args;
}
```

expands to

```
function go() {
    var args = function () {
            var len = arguments.length;
            var args$2 = Array(len);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                args$2[i] = arguments[i];
            }
            return args$2;
        }.apply(this, arguments);
    return args;
}
```

Don't know if that would kill optimization though...

Comment: Apply is the only thing that doesn't kill optimization. Array.apply(null, arguments) is almost as fast as the for loop but breaks if arguments has only one element.